# how to count the given patern from a given string using php

Tags: php

I want to count the given pattern i.e(- - - - - - -) in the string.

```
$a="My company - - - - - - name is - - - - - -.";
$b="cmp,hyd";
```

if found more than one time 
then replace with cmp and hyd in the pattern.

Comment: your question is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use substr_count php function to get counts and preg_replace to replace values.

```
$a="My company - - - - - name is - - - - -."; 
$b="cmp,hyd";
$tb = explode(",", $b);
$d_count = substr_count($a, '- - - - -');
echo $a;
echo "<br/>";
if($d_count == 2)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++)
    {
        $a = preg_replace('/- - - - -/', $tb[$i], $a, 1);
    }
}
echo $a;
```